# Trying to allow postgresql to be accessed remotely always timeout expired

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

i tried to "enable" my postgresql13 to be accessed remotely.
So i tried to connect via pgadmin4 and it always said :

```
Unable to connect to server:

timeout expired
```

The ip when i check with command

```
ip a
```

it gave me

```
192.168.xxx.xxx/24
```

have tried both using with "/24" and without it

this is my pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
host    all             all             all                     md5
```

this is my postgresql.conf

```
# - Connection Settings -

#listen_addresses = '*'     # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
#port = 5435                # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql, /tmp'  # comma-separated list of directories
                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)
```

I've already read from multiple sources here and there, change the listen addresses to become '*', and if wanted to change port, change it in the postgresql.conf port=desiredport

Am i missing something?

this is what i enter in the pgadmin4
[image: pgadmin4]

Comment: The host does not exist, or you have a network or firewall problem.

Comment: Besides, you forgot to remove the comment for `listen_addresses`.

Comment: the host is exist and ok i've just realized the comment of listen_address and already removed the comment and on the port=5435. also in the firewall i already allow the port. now i'm really confused because like i've tried everything on google :'( btw after i removed the comment i also already restart the service

Comment: There must be a firewall or some other network problem you forgot.

Comment: There are multiple places a firewall could exist.

Comment: Come back to clear this, yes as Laurenz Albe said it was a network problem which caused by proxy things. The config already OK, but got caught with another problems when i used an older version of Aqua Data Studio it gave me "The authentication type 10 is not supported". While in pgadmin4 it was working like charm, maybe someone knows how to "work around" this? So it's able to be accessed by both database GUI ?